# How to make `choose.dir` run only the first time that user runs a function in R?

Tags: r, function

I use `choose.dir()` in my simple function below to pop up a windows-type screen for user to choose a working directory for the `png` files produced in the function.

## Question

However, I was wondering how I could have this `choose.dir()` to pop-up **ONLY on the first run of the function? (not each time user wants to run the function)**

Right now, the `choose.dir()` window pops up each time I run the function.

```
Pch = function(n = 5){

setwd(choose.dir())    ## How to make this run only the first time that user runs the function?


for(i in 1:n) {

 png(paste0("plot_", i, ".png"), width = 1200, height = 1300, res = 200)

  plot( rnorm(1e2) )

  dev.off()

    }
}

## TEST HERE:
Pch()
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't set the working directory in your function. Just use the current working directory or have them pass an (optional) directory path as a parameter to your function. You should minimize "side effects" when writing functions. That will make it much easier to compose in ways you may not have anticipated. But if you insist, look into using `options()` for storing preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could initialize a flag in the global environment and change its value at first call of the function. Let the function then check that flag to see if the function has been called before:

```
## Initialize flag in global environment:
.GlobalEnv$isDirChosen <- FALSE

Pch = function(n = 5){      
    ## Check if function has been called before:
    if (.GlobalEnv$isDirChosen == FALSE){
        setwd(choose.dir())    ## How to make this run only the first time that user runs the function?
        .GlobalEnv$isDirChosen <- TRUE  ## Change value of flag
    }

    for(i in 1:n) {         
        png(paste0("plot_", i, ".png"), width = 1200, height = 1300, res = 200)         
        plot(rnorm(1e2))            
        dev.off()           
    }
}

## TEST HERE:
Pch()
```

**Edit**

I agree with @MrFlick on minimizing side effects. It would be better not to change the working directory at all. You can achieve this by passing the path returned by `choose.dir` to your graphics device. Also, if you do not want to have to initialize the global variable outside of the function, you can just check for existence of the variable instead of checking if it is `NA`. Here is the slightly altered code:

```
Pch = function(n = 5){
    ## Check if a path has been chosen. If not prompt user:
    if (!exists("pathForPlots", where = .GlobalEnv)){
        .GlobalEnv$pathForPlots <- choose.dir() 
    }

    ## Produce your plots in the chosen path (witout changing the wd):
    for(i in 1:n) {     
        png(file.path(.GlobalEnv$pathForPlots, paste0("plot_", i, ".png")), 
                width = 1200, height = 1300, res = 200)     
        plot(rnorm(1e2))        
        dev.off()       
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your value of `.GlobalEnv$pathForPlots` and does that folder already exist?

Comment: If you don't want to initialize `.GlobalEnv$pathForPlots` outside the function, you can do it by checking if the variable exists instead of checking if it is `NA`. I'll adapt the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! Everything works fine except one thing. If you set the argument `n` to ,say, `20`, the function produces 20 png files and stores them in the chosen directory. **BUT,** if after that, you change `n` to any smaller number, say, `10`, the function *only overwrites the first 10 `png` files from the previous run!* So, **you still see 20 png files in the folder**, which is very confusing. In other words, we need the function to empty the folder when a new run of the function is executed!